# com.google.appengine:appengine:+ vs com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:+

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gradle, build-script

I am new to gradle concept. I'm doing gradle for app engine (I don't know maven or ant) and I gone through in [https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/gradle] but I can't able to understand the difference between the:

```
buildscript {
     repositories {
     jcenter()
     mavenCentral()
   }
dependencies {
     classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:+'
   }
}
```

and:

```
repositories {
     jcenter()
     mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
     providedCompile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
     compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine:+'
}
```

I searched in the internet I can't able to understand? Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 1):

It may be confusing at the very beginning but is quite easy. With gradle you do manage the project but both gradle and the project that is managed can have their own dependencies. So, if you'd like e.g. use guava to compile your project files it will be:

```
repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
   compile 'com.google.guava:guava:22.0'
}
```

but if you'd like to use guava in `build.gradle` file then the following piece of code is necessary:

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
      mavenCentral()
   }
   dependencies {
      classpath 'com.google.guava:guava:22.0'
   }
}
```

So `buildscript` is used to configure `build.gradle` *itself*.

In the example provided `buildscript` block is used to configure dependency for plugin that is applied later on in `build.gradle` and the second block configures the dependencies for the project itself.

Comment: Thanks for you response, sorry but still I am in confusion @Opal

Comment: @Prakash, what does still confuse you?

Comment: @Prakash, please have a look here as well: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#sec:build_script_external_dependencies

Comment: @Prakash if you found my answer helpful please upvote or accept it.